# moving glass pane between frames

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, glasspane

I'm dragging component from one frame in  main monitor to another frame in secondary monitor ,and while I'm dragging it the component painted in glasspane, I can see the glasspane over the main mointor ,but after the mouse reach the secondary monitor, the glasspane disappears? Can any one help me in this? How I can paint the glasspane over the secondary monitor?

Here is some pieces of my code:

```
public class Main_Frame extends JFrame

{

     public Main_Frame (){
        //adding  the content of main JFrame
        setGlassPane(new  ImageGlassPane());
        //detect other screens and making object of Second_Frame for each
     }
}

public class Second_Frame extends JDialog{
    public Second_Frame(){
       super(new Frame(MultiMonitor.getInstance().getNextDevice().getDefaultConfiguration()), 
          Title, false);
       setGlassPane(new  ImageGlassPane());
    }

}

    public class ImageGlassPane() extends JPanel{
public ImageGlassPane() {
           setOpaque(false);

     }

     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if ( !isVisible()) {
            return;
        }
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int x = (int) (location.getX() - (width * zoom / 2));
        int y = (int) (location.getY() - (height * zoom / 2));

        if (visibleRect != null) {
            g2.setClip(visibleRect);
        }

        if (visibleRect != null) {
            Area clip = new Area(visibleRect);
            g2.setClip(clip);
        }

        g2.drawImage(image, x, y, (int) (width * zoom), (int) (height * zoom), null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However you are painting the component in the glass pane on the first frame, you will need to do for the second frame as well.  This sounds like it is not a two monitor issue, but a two frame issue instead.

Comment: I build class extends jpanel and draw the glasspane content through it ,so im using the same class for both frames to set the glasspane at them , so using the same paintComponent function to draw image inside glasspane ,but it appear over main frame and not over second frame ,does it related to graphics object? also the second frame is Jdialog and i a sign to it owner Jframe

Comment: Sounds like there is something strange going on, I would suggest creating a SSCCE.